# Need All the posts with id, title and date

Tags: posts, api, web-services

I need all the post ids with the corresponding title and post date.

Currently getting only ids

```
 $posts_array = get_posts( 'posts_per_page=999999999999&fields=ids' );
```

need

```
[{
"id" : 9,
"post_date" : "2014-06-11 07:04:55",
"post_title" : "title.."
}, 
    {..}, 
    {..},..
]
```

---

Scenario:

1. Post will be used to show in tablet/Mobile (with infinite scroll).
2. Call web service to get Posts.
3. the post must return result in a paging manner like 1-20, 20-40 (from all posts) for subsequent calls.
4. Don't want to load all the posts as it will arise performance issue.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Have you checked the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)? This seems like a "read the manual"-question.

Comment: You have `fields=ids`, so what did you expect? :)

Comment: need id, tiles and post date, is there any shortcut way not using recursive call ie; again requesting title+post date from ids

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to get a list of posts, and then the [`WP_Post` member variables](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) to get and display the data that you need

You van do something like this. You can refine it as you need

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1); 
$posts= get_posts( $args );
if ($posts) {
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        echo '<p>' . $post->post_title . '(' . $post->ID . ')'  . ' was posted on  ' .  $post->post_date . '</p>';
    }
}
```

This will output

> TEST POST SUB(312) was posted on 2014-05-29 15:47:26

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? Was my answer useful in solving your problem. If yes, please accept my answer. If your problem is not solved, where is my code lacking. If you solved your own problem it would be nice if you post that as an answer to your question

Comment: Hi @Pieter. Your post is good for front end, but I'm using web Service and the response must be in JSON. I need that is a single line query(if possible). I want that also in paging style ie: from post 1-20, 20-40 (from all posts).

Comment: Please update your question as your question is misleading